# vim EasyGrep: Opens split windows and loads each searched file

Tags: vim

I recently installed the [EasyGrep Plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2438) for vim. It works very well, except for one thing which is bothering me: When I am using `<leader>vv` (mapped to `EgMapGrepCurrentWord_v`) to search for the word under the cursor, EasyGrep opens a split window and loads each file it searches into the split.

This seems to be time consuming and is also very distracting. Do you know of an option to disable this?

Comment: What do you mean by *" EasyGrep opens a split window and loads each file it searches into the split."*? Do you see the content of all the files loaded in the split? All I see is the quickfix window opening instantly with a list of filenames and line numbers. Which is exactly the purpose of this great plugin (`<leader>vr` rocks).

Comment: Yes, I see the content of each file for a a flash second.

Comment: What options, if any, did you set for EasyGrep?

Comment: I have no extra options set. I installed EasyGrep using `vundle`, so one can find the plugin here: https://github.com/vim-scripts/EasyGrep/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular behavior comes about because of how Vim's builtin `:vimgrep` command works. From Vim's documentation:

> To be able to do this Vim loads each file as if it is being edited.

This must be what causes the side-effect of the flashing windows. If you find this distracting, you can consider using the external grep command `:grep` instead of the `:vimgrep` command. By default, EasyGrep is configured to use `:vimgrep`. You can switch to `:grep` by setting your .vimrc with the following setting.

```
    let g:EasyGrepCommand=1
```